# Ajax and Request Scoped beans in JSF 1.2 and Rich Faces

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, jakarta-ee, richfaces

I'm using JSF 1.2 and RichFaces 3.3, I have a page called NewsItemDetails with the following structure

```
<h:form>
  <h:panelBar>
    <h:panelBarItem>
      <myTag:searchModule />
    </h:panelBarItem>
  </h:panelBar>
</h:form>
```

and the backing bean of that page is of a request scope, and here is a snippet of the faces-config.xml:

```
<managed-bean>
  <managed-bean-name>newsItemDetails</managed-bean-name>
  <managed-bean-class>class.location...</managed-bean-class>
  <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
  <managed-property>
     <property-name>id</property-name>
     <value>#{param['id']}</value>
  </managed-property>
</managed-bean>
```

And to be complete here's a snippet of the searchModule tag:

```
<ui:composition>
   <rich:tabPanel>
     <rich:tab label="Images">
       <h:panelGrid columns="2">
         <h:inputText value="#{newsItemDetails.searchLabel}" />
         <a4j:commandButton value="Search" actionListener="#{newsItemDetails.onSearch}" reRender="mediaItemsSearchResults, imagesDataTable" />
       </h:panelGrid>

       <a4j:outputPanel id="mediaItemsSearchResults" ajaxRendered="true">
         <rich:dataTable id="imagesDataTable" value="#{newsItemDetails.searchResults}" var="image">
           <h:column>
             <h:outputText value="#{image.title}"/>
           </h:column>
         </rich:dataTable>
       </a4j:outputPanel>

     </rich:tab>
   </rich:tabPanel>
</ui:composition>
```

Now the problem is, whenever I hit the search button, the action listener is never called,
but I could see a request sent to the server through Firebug. And here's the strange thing if I call the same searchModule tag, just outside the rich:panelBarItem and I hit the search button the action listener is called, but the dataTable is not re-rendered, and it's only called the first time I hit the button.

So if anyone has a clue why this is happening, I would be more than grateful.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the panelBarItem rendered by default when you enter the page for the first time? Why are you using a h:commandButton instead of a a4j:commandButton if you want to do an ajax call? (the reRender attribute doesn't make sense in a h:commandButton).

Comment: The panelBarItem has a condition but by default is rendered, and regarding the h:commandButton, I'm actually using a4j:commandButton, but it was a typo

Comment: The only thing that I can thik of that could stop the actionListener from being called is that commandButton is not rendered in the restoreView phase. Try changing the scope of the backing bean from request to session. If this fix it, then the problem is that something that contains the commandButton is not considered to be rendered in the restoreView phase.

Comment: I think that the problem is in the rich:panelBar and its child components, as I've said earlier I call the tag outside it and it works, and the action listener gets called, except that id doesn't rerender the dataTable, but from within the rich:panelBar non of that happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out the answer, apparently the scope of the backing bean had to be set to session scope instead of request. Having done that everything works great.
So the entry in the faces-config.xml is:

```
<managed-bean>
  <managed-bean-name>newsItemDetails</managed-bean-name>
  <managed-bean-class>class.location...</managed-bean-class>
  <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

And as you can see I had to remove the  entry, and instead get it from the request object in the backing bean.

Thanks all.